# How to get the row data according to the id in django

Tags: python, django

I have a Class like this

```
class udl(models.Model):
  uid = models.IntegerField()
  url = models.CharField(max_length=1000,default='')
```

Assume i have Table like this

```
10|data1
10|data2
11|data3
12|data4
```

how can i show the list of data in templates like data1 and data2 if the id is 10.

```
{%for d in dislike%}
<ul>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="box box-danger box-solid collapsed-box">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title" style="word-wrap:break-word;width:560px;" data-widget="collapse">{{d.title}}</h3>
          <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i><span data-original-title="Number of People Hate it" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="badge bg-red">{{d.count}}</span>
            <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
          </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
        </div><!-- /.box-header -->
        <div style="display: none;" class="box-body">
          {%for u in udlist%}
          <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
            <li>
              <a href="{{u.url}}" target="_blank">{{u.url}}***#Here how can i show list of url data for the individual id.*** 
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          {%endfor%}
        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
      </div>
    </div>
</ul>
{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
udl.objects.filter(uid=10)  # Where udl is your model class
```

That should return the rows with `uid=10`

You can see [docs for Making queries with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/)